# Show large amount of attributed text efficiently using textkit without using paging

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, core-text, textkit

I have a large text file and I need to show it continuously, like one can do in textview. However, the rendering of the text takes a lot of time in `UILable`/`UITextView`. I have tried working with **TextKit** to only render the portion of the text visible on screen but was unsuccessful. TextContainer's height need to be set depending on the content height for it to work and that is no better than using `UITextView` or `UILabel`.
Is there a way to only render the portion of the text that is visible on screen without using paging. Please share your thoughts on if that is achievable with high performance.

thanks